# How to load classes, resources, jars dynamically in java?

Tags: java, spring, maven, ant, classloader

Here we exhibit two project structure.

1. first one for **multiple projects**
2. and another one for **single project** structure.

we want to assemble single project that consist of multiple projects. Our requirement is to load it's dependency like **classes**, **resources**, **jars** from different location dynamically by java program. without adding class path entry into it's jar **MANIFEST.MF**.

You are permitted to add java options at run time for recognizing class path but we are preferred to load dynamically by java program.

```
/opt/java/chorke/multiple/projects/home/
    ├─ bin/
    │   ├─ mspn/
    │   │   ├─ lib/
    │   │   │   ├─ chorke-mspn-utlity-2.0.00-SNAPSHOT.jar
    │   │   │   └─ chorke-mspn-webapp-2.0.00-SNAPSHOT.jar
    │   │   ├─ chorke-mspn-server-2.0.00-SNAPSHOT.jar         [executable jar]
    │   │   ├─ README.md
    │   │   └─ LICENSE
    │   ├─ mllp/
    │   │   ├─ lib/
    │   │   │   ├─ chorke-mllp-utlity-2.0.00-SNAPSHOT.jar
    │   │   │   └─ chorke-mllp-webapp-2.0.00-SNAPSHOT.jar
    │   │   ├─ chorke-mllp-server-2.0.00-SNAPSHOT.jar         [executable jar]
    │   │   ├─ README.md
    │   │   └─ LICENSE
    │   └─ itis/
    │       ├─ lib/
    │       │   ├─ chorke-itis-utlity-2.0.00-SNAPSHOT.jar
    │       │   └─ chorke-itis-webapp-2.0.00-SNAPSHOT.jar
    │       ├─ chorke-itis-server-2.0.00-SNAPSHOT.jar         [executable jar]
    │       ├─ README.md
    │       └─ LICENSE
    ├─ lib/
    │   ├─ commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar
    │   ├─ ...more...hidden...jars...here.jar
    │   ├─ slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar
    ├─ opt/
    │   ├─ org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86-4.4.2.jar
    │   ├─ org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86-4.4.2.jar
    │   ├─ ...more...optional...hidden...jars...here.jar
    │   └─ org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64-4.4.2.jar
    └─ etc/
        ├─ mspn/
        │   ├─ application.properties
        │   ├─ application.yml
        │   └─ log4j.xml
        ├─ mllp/
        │   ├─ application.properties
        │   ├─ application.yml
        │   └─ log4j.xml
        └─ itis/
            ├─ application.properties
            ├─ application.yml
            └─ log4j.xml
```

Here we split the multiple project structure to single project for your kind consideration.

```
/opt/java/chorke/single/project/home/
    ├─ bin/
    │   └─ itis/
    │       ├─ lib/
    │       │   ├─ chorke-itis-utlity-2.0.00-SNAPSHOT.jar
    │       │   └─ chorke-itis-webapp-2.0.00-SNAPSHOT.jar
    │       ├─ chorke-itis-server-2.0.00-SNAPSHOT.jar         [executable jar]
    │       ├─ README.md
    │       └─ LICENSE
    ├─ lib/
    │   ├─ commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar
    │   ├─ ...more...hidden...jars...here.jar
    │   ├─ slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar
    ├─ opt/
    │   ├─ org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86-4.4.2.jar
    │   ├─ org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86-4.4.2.jar
    │   ├─ ...more...optional...hidden...jars...here.jar
    │   └─ org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64-4.4.2.jar
    └─ etc/
        └─ itis/
            ├─ application.properties
            ├─ application.yml
            └─ log4j.xml
```

## Edited

Let's say we want to run `chorke-itis-server-2.0.00-SNAPSHOT.jar` by

```
java -jar ./bin/itis/chorke-itis-server-2.0.00-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

command but it will not executed as lacks of it's dependency in class path, such as:-

1. Own jar library `./bin/itis/lib/*.jar`
2. Common jar library `./lib/*.jar`
3. Optional jar library `./opt/*.jar`
4. Config resources `./etc/itis/*.*`

These dependency will not loaded as usual process. We should do more to recognized these class path. It would be pass from command line by providing class path parameter or dynamically by java program.

Could you please help us to build dynamic class loader by helping of core java or any kind of opensource framework?

Comment: If these are the JAR's you created, then you can create a local-repository and point maven to it. If they are available in maven-central or so, you can directly put the dependencies in POM.xml and they will already be imported and in your path, when you compile the project using maven install.

Comment: Mr.  [We are Borg](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1510701/we-are-borg) for production environment how to assemble a project to load  classes, resources, jars from different location dynamically by java program.

Comment: You have to go for [OSGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi) to do so. There is a Maven plugin that helps on creating and packaging modules.

Comment: Mr. [Stefan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1264321/stefan) your right, we are not interested [OSGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi). We want to handle it simply by using Java default Class Loader like. `System.load(filename)` or `System.loadLibrary(libname)` some things like that.

Comment: You can always create the same local repo you have on your development machine on the server-side as well. Many companies do it this way!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the single sample project structure as your demand while `BootstrapMainApplication` is the main class inside the `com.chorke.boot` package for executing the java application :-

```
/opt/java/chorke/itis/project/home/
    ├─ bin/
    │   └─ itis/
    │       ├─ lib/
    │       │   ├─ chorke-itis-utlity-2.0.00-SNAPSHOT.jar
    │       │   └─ chorke-itis-webapp-2.0.00-SNAPSHOT.jar
    │       ├─ chorke-itis-server-2.0.00-SNAPSHOT.jar         [executable jar]
    │       ├─ classes/
    │       ├─ README.md
    │       └─ LICENSE
    ├─ lib/
    │   ├─ usr/
    │   │   ├─ chorke-amqp-client-2.0.00-SNAPSHOT.jar
    │   │   └─ chorke-comn-spring-2.0.00-SNAPSHOT.jar
    │   └─ gpl/
    │       ├─ activemq-broker-5.10.2
    │       ├─ commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar
    │       ├─ ..more...and..more..jar
    │       └─ slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar
    ├─ etc/
    │   └─ itis/
    │       ├─ application.properties
    │       ├─ application.yml
    │       └─ log4j.xml
    ├─ launch.bat
    └─ launch.sh
```

Considering this project structure you can write **bat** or **shell** script named **launch.bat** and **launch.sh** for Windows as well as Linux platform.

#### launch.bat

```
goto launch

:launch
    SET CKI_HOME=.
    SET BIN_PATH=%CKI_HOME%\bin
    SET LIB_PATH=%CKI_HOME%\lib
    SET ETC_PATH=%CKI_HOME%\etc
    SET ITI_HOME=%BIN_PATH%\itis
    SET CLS_PATH=%ETC_PATH%\itis\;%ITI_HOME%\classes\
    SET CLS_PATH=%CLS_PATH%;%LIB_PATH%\gpl\*;%LIB_PATH%\usr\*;%ITI_HOME%\lib\*;%ITI_HOME%\*

    @REM SET CMD_EXCE=java -cp %CLS_PATH% com.chorke.boot.BootstrapMainApplication
    SET CMD_EXCE=java -classpath %CLS_PATH% com.chorke.boot.BootstrapMainApplication
    %CMD_EXCE%
```

For Linux platform using this shell script may work fine

#### launch.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

function launch(){
    CKI_HOME='.';
    BIN_PATH="$CKI_HOME/bin";
    LIB_PATH="$CKI_HOME/lib";
    ETC_PATH="$CKI_HOME/etc";
    ITI_HOME="$BIN_PATH/itis";
    CLS_PATH="$ETC_PATH/itis/:$ITI_HOME/classes/";
    CLS_PATH="$CLS_PATH:$LIB_PATH/gpl/*:$LIB_PATH/usr/*:$ITI_HOME/lib/*:$ITI_HOME/*";

    #CMD_EXCE="java -cp $CLS_PATH com.chorke.boot.BootstrapMainApplication";
    CMD_EXCE="java -classpath $CLS_PATH com.chorke.boot.BootstrapMainApplication";
    $CMD_EXCE;
}

launch;
```

It's suppose to me these script would be helpful to build your own application ecosystem/structure as well as able to load classes/config/library from different location.